# sending String using servlet while dowloading in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gxt, gwt-rpc

i am using GWT

I trying to dowload a file using Servlet.

I have `fileId` on the client side.

i have my servlet ready to look for the file using `fileId` and send back to client.

But on the Client side.
I dont understand how to send this id and retrieve this on server side to use it.

```
String fileId = "aValidId"
Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "DownloadFileServlet", "", "");
```

Can any one help me to do this.

If this question is repeated , please send me a link (i could not find it )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply append the parameter to the servlet path like below

```
String fileId = "aValidId"
Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +
                          "DownloadFileServlet?fileId ="+fileId , "", "");
```

And in `servlet` get the parameter like below:

```
String myParam = req.getParameter("myparam");
```

And please go through the below link for encoding and for other techniques..

http://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/